What is the power consumption of this 5-transistor DISO OTA?
Consider a 5-transistor DISO (differential-input-single-output) OTA (operational transconductance amplifier) (see image), biased with known gate voltage Vb (resulting in a known current, Ib). The top is connected to positive power supply, Vdd. Bottom n-MOS transistor (yielding bias current Ib) has source connected to ground. N-mos transistors have bulk connected to ground, p-mos transistors have bulk connected to VDD. V1 and V2 are two known inputs for the OTA. You can assume the transistors are in saturation (i.e., voltage across the drain and source are much, much higher than its intrinsic thermal voltage). How do you calculate the power consumption of the OTA? Would it be equivalent to (V1 - V2)Ib? Or, perhaps, Vdd*Ib?
As far as I'm concerned, all 5 transistors consume power. Let's ignore the power consumption of any potential elements following this OTA (in other words, the current going out will ultimately result in another component consuming power, but let's disregard that). Rather, let's just consider the power internally, of just the 5 transistors inside this OTA. I'm rather new to dissecting circuits like these (EE is NOT my primary area of study), but I am curious to know if there's a trick in deriving the power (i.e., if the current mirror here makes it easy to pick out)
My TA for my neuromorphic integrated biolectronics course stated that the power consumed by the OTA is \$V_{dd}\times I_b\$, however, that seems suspiciously easy? Why would this represent the power consumed by all the transistor elements? Is there a way to prove/rationalize this?
Image - Carver Mead - Analog VSLI and Neural Systems (Ch5 Transconductance Amplifier)


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Let's ignore the power consumption of any potential elements following this OTA (in other words, the current going out will ultimately result in another component consuming power, but let's disregard that).

You can ring-fence the whole circuit and, in doing so you make the very reasonable assumption that the inputs are insulated from their respective MOSFET channels and, no power passes through those inputs of any consequence. This means that all the power dissipated by the ring-fenced circuit comes from the power supply (\$V_{dd}\$ and \$I_d\$).
So, in ring-fencing the circuit you turn it into a two terminal black box that is fed a voltage of \$V_{dd}\$ at a current of \$I_b\$.
If you attached a wattmeter to the supply infeed it would register an input power of \$V_{dd}\times I_b\$.

Is there a way to prove/rationalize this?

Our home electricity meters know nothing about what we have connected regarding our appliances; it just treats whatever circuit that follows it as a black box. There is nothing fundamentally inaccurate or flawed about this method.

Thank you for your thorough answer!

if the load has a galvanic skin voltage or some resistance then it is non-ring-fenced circuit. Also the OTA will match the load at Vout=Vdd/2.  Right?  The better question is how does one compute quiescent power.

I'm not asking the question and neither are you tony

You're right that each transistor in this arrangement will dissipate power, but the sum of all the individual power sinks (each transistor) cannot be more or less than the power dissisated by the whole system, by the law of conservation of energy.
Assuming no current leaves or enters via the output, so \$I_{OUT}=0A\$, then by KCL, current entering at the top (from the positive supply \$V_{DD}\$, current which I will call \$I_{DD}\$) must equal current leaving via the bottom (to ground), which is \$I_B\$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{DD} &= I_B \\ \\
P_{ALL} &= I_{DD} \times V_{DD} \\ \\
&= I_B \times V_{DD} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
That's the easiest solution, valid in spite of our ignorance of the state of any individual transistor. We're able to trust this result, because we know that the Lumped Element Model (or "LEM", from which we obtain KCL, KVL and Ohm's law, amongst others) is established upon fundamental physics concepts, such as the law of conservation of energy.
If you wish, you can obtain the same result by considering all individual transistors, by assigning some arbitrary voltages and currents, and applying KVL and KCL. Again, I'll assume \$I_{OUT}=0\$, so that we need only consider one current variable for each path of the long-tailed-pair. I'll also omit any branches/loops that do not carry current, such as gate connections, since they won't participate in KCL or KVL for the loops that concern us here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
KCL:
$$ I_b = I_1 + I_2 $$
KVL:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{Qb} + V_{Q1} + V_{Q3} &= V_{DD} \\ \\
V_{Qb} + V_{Q2} + V_{Q4} &= V_{DD} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Power:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{Qb} &= V_{Qb}I_b \\ \\
P_{Q1} &= V_{Q1}I_1 \\ \\
P_{Q2} &= V_{Q2}I_2 \\ \\
P_{Q3} &= V_{Q3}I_1 \\ \\
P_{Q4} &= V_{Q4}I_2 \\ \\
\\
P_{ALL} &= P_{Qb} + P_{Q1} + P_{Q2} + P_{Q3} + P_{Q4} \\ \\
&= V_{Qb}I_b + V_{Q1}I_1 + V_{Q2}I_2 + V_{Q3}I_1 + V_{Q4}I_2 \\ \\
&= V_{Qb}(I_1 + I_2) + (V_{Q1} + V_{Q3})I_1 + (V_{Q2} + V_{Q4})I_2 \\ \\
&= V_{Qb}I_1 + V_{Qb}I_2 + (V_{Q1} + V_{Q3})I_1 + (V_{Q2} + V_{Q4})I_2 \\ \\
&= (V_{Qb} + V_{Q1} + V_{Q3})I_1 + (V_{Qb} + V_{Q2} + V_{Q4})I_2 \\ \\
&= V_{DD}I_1 + V_{DD}I_2 \\ \\
&= V_{DD}(I_1 + I_2) \\ \\
&= I_bV_{DD}
\end{aligned}
$$
That may not be the most elegant way to do this, but it does show the same total power dissipation. Notice that's it's completely independent of the state of any individual transistor, or any value of \$I_1\$ or \$I_2\$. That's to be expected if physics is correct about its claim that energy in must equal energy out (as heat in this case), regardless of how that energy is distributed between the participating elements.

Thinking about the problem like this makes a lot of sense, thank you for pointing out I can apply the Lumped Element model. Cheers!

The gate current is negligble.
There is only one current to ground = supply return Idd.
Therefore Idd=Ib or Pd with no-load MUST be Pd=Vdd*Ib.
It really is that simple with one gnd current = Ib.
However, if a load is added, then both amp and load share current and dissipate power.
